# Center text horizontally and vertically in a textarea

Tags: html, textarea, center

How can I center text in a textarea horizontally and vertically?

HTML

```
  <div id="visu">
            <div id="element1"class="flex-item"> 
                <textarea class= "name" id="name1" >Apud has gentes, quarum exordiens initium ab Assyriis </textarea>   
             </div> 
             <div id="element2" class="flex-item"> 
                <textarea class= "name" id="name2">Ultima Syriarum est Palaestina   </textarea>   
             </div> 
             <div id="element3" class="flex-item"> 
                <textarea class="name" id="name3">Saepe posset commodi contentionem honoris quam incidissent optimis adipisci commod.</textarea>   
             </div> 

        </div>
```

CSS
        #visu {
                position:absolute;
                width:95%;
                left:-5ppx;
                top:50px;
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:row;
                flex-wrap:wrap;
                justify-content:space-around;
            }
            #visu .flex-item  {
                // position:absolute; 
                 display:table;
                 width:30%;
                 margin-bottom:30px;
                 height:160px;
                 margin-right:-20px;

```
        }

       .flex-item .name {
            display:table-cell;
            border:3px solid blue; border-radius:10px;
            padding:20px; box-sizing:border-box;
            background-color:white;
            width=150px;
            height:180px;
            font-size:16px;
            text-align:center:
            vertical-align:middle;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS should be

```
<style>
    #visu {
        position:absolute;
        width:95%;
        left:-5ppx;
        top:50px;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        justify-content:space-around;
    }

    #visu .flex-item  {
        /* position:absolute; */
        display:table;
        width:30%;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        height:160px;
        margin-right:-20px;
    }

    .flex-item .name {
        display:table-cell;
        border:3px solid blue; border-radius:10px;
        padding:20px; box-sizing:border-box;
        background-color:white;
        width:150px;
        height:180px;
        font-size:16px;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
</style>
```

Please check your code

Comment: I does not seem to work. Could you check in my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Apud has gentes, quarum exordiens initium ab Assyriis    

              
                Ultima Syriarum est Palaestina      

              
                Saepe posset commodi contentionem honoris quam incidissent optimis adipisci commod.

Comment: You have got to take out the textarea tag out of second div one.

Answer (score 0):

```
   #visu {
    position:absolute;
    width:95%;
    left:-5ppx;
    top:50px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:space-around;
}

   #visu .name  {
    /* position:absolute; */
    display:table;
    width:30%;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    height:160px;
    margin-right:-20px;
}

    #visu textarea.name {
    display:table-cell;
    border:3px solid blue; border-radius:10px;
    padding:20px; box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:white;
    width:150px;
    height:180px;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Also change the css as mentioned

Comment: It does not seem to work. Could you check in my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Check below code to display center aligned content in textarea [vertical & horizontal]

```css
 .flex-item .name {
          
            border:3px solid blue; border-radius:10px;
            padding:20px; box-sizing:border-box;
            background-color:white;            
            height:180px;
            font-size:16px;
            text-align:center;display: inline-block;  padding-top:50px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="visu">
            <div id="element1"class="flex-item"> 
                <textarea class= "name" id="name1" >Apud has gentes, quarum exordiens initium ab Assyriis </textarea>   
             </div> 
             <div id="element2" class="flex-item"> 
                <textarea class= "name" id="name2">Ultima Syriarum est Palaestina   </textarea>   
             </div> 
             <div id="element3" class="flex-item"> 
                <textarea class="name" id="name3">Saepe posset commodi contentionem honoris quam incidissent optimis adipisci commod.</textarea>   
             </div> 

        </div>
```